# Can't seem to get RemoteIpFilter (https) to correctly interact with spring webflow

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, spring-webflow

I run a configuration of Nginx (ssl) -> apache -> tomcat. Nginx decodes the ssl and forwards the request to apache (and then to tomcat) with the `X-SSL-Request=1` header. I was looking for a good way to enabling correct ssl behavior in my application without making my apache config any more complex. This feels like it is the better solution in case we decide to deprecate apache (thus removing the AJP protocol usage and relying solely on http). Alternative is to use apache to change `env.HTTPS` to `on`. However I am very curious where I went wrong with this approach.

Here's my filter configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>protocolHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>X-SSL-Request</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>protocolHeaderHttpsValue</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Now I have a controller for testing out what the actual controller sees after all this, I get:

```
Request protocol HTTP/1.0 
Request secure true 
Request server port 443 
Request url http://localsecure.xxx/common/requestTest.html 
Request uri /common/requestTest.html 
Request scheme https
```

Now spring webflow seems to read that as "http" is the protocol to create redirects with, and so all redirects render as `http://localsecure.xxx/...` rather than the intended `https://localsecure.xxx/...`. The only clue I have is that tomcat still thinks the request url is `http://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `RemoteIpFilter`. The `getRequestURL` method is not overwritten and handled by the original request.

**Update** Kudos to the project. It is already fixed: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=remoteipfilter&list_id=135019